# Modificar perfil de usuario

Tags: linux, opensuse

Cómo hago para que la terminal de Linux reconozca que he tecleado un comando con privilegios de administrador y me pida solamente la contraseña de root sin tener que volver a teclear todo el comando otra vez....¿modificando el fichero .bashrc?

Gracias

Comment: Tu problema es que cuando pones un comando con sudo, pones la contraseña y te obliga a poner otra vez el comando no?PD: Mira si esta respuesta en [StackOverflow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470383/how-to-avoid-being-prompted-for-a-password-by-sudo/470387) te ayuda. SI es asi, la traduzco

Comment: La respuesta correcta en la pregunta linkeada por @Capt.Teach seria: https://askubuntu.com/questions/470383/how-to-avoid-being-prompted-for-a-password-by-sudo/470387#answer-470462. Incluso con esta alternativa podés evitar escribir la password. La seleccionada como respuesta presenta varios riesgos de seguridad.

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa es incrementar el tiempo en el cual tienes que volver a ingresar la contraseña después de ejecutar con comando con "sudo".

```
# sudo visudo
```

Cambiar el valor de la siguiente directiva al tiempo deseado:

Defaults        env_reset,timestamp_timeout=20